Unable to Display Data from QSqlQueryModel in QML ListView
Description:
I am encountering an issue where I am unable to display data retrieved from a QSqlQueryModel in a QML ListView. Despite successfully loading the data in the C++ backend and confirming its presence, the QML ListView shows undefined values for each item.
Here are the relevant details of my setup:
Environment: I am using Qt for application development, with version [insert version number]. The application is developed using C++ for the backend logic and QML for the frontend UI.
Issue Description: When attempting to display data retrieved from a QSqlQueryModel in a QML ListView, the ListView shows undefined values for each item. However, I have confirmed that the data is successfully loaded into the QSqlQueryModel in the C++ backend.
Troubleshooting Steps: I have verified that the data is correctly loaded into the QSqlQueryModel by logging the data in the C++ backend. Additionally, I have checked the role names defined in the roleNames() function of the QSqlQueryModel and ensured that they match the property names used in QML.
Expected Behavior: I expect the QML ListView to display the data retrieved from the QSqlQueryModel, with each item showing the corresponding values for host, label, tag, grpc_port, grpc_username, and grpc_password.
Code Samples:
qrc:/qt/qml/content/AgentPanel.qml:104:21: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString

But in debugging console I can see my model correctly loaded in c++ class:
Query Executed Successfully: true
Number of Rows Retrieved: 27
Row Data: "localhost" "Agent 1" "tag1" 50051 "user1" "pass1"

This is my main.cpp :
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set_qt_environment();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<InitDb>("com.example", 1, 0, "InitDb");

    InitDb db;
    // db.initDb();

    AgentModel agentModel;
    agentModel.loadAgents();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("agentModel", &agentModel);

    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/qt/qml/Main/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
                &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
                [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    },
    Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.addImportPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qml");
    engine.addImportPath(":/");

    engine.load(url);
  
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return app.exec();
}

My agentModel.cpp
#include "agentModel.h"
 
AgentModel::AgentModel(QObject* parent) : QSqlQueryModel(parent) {}

void AgentModel::loadAgents()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT host, label, tag, grpc_port, grpc_username, grpc_password FROM agents");

    if (!query.exec()) {
        qDebug() << "Error executing query:" << query.lastError().text();
        return;
    }

    // Clear any existing data in the model
    clear();

    // Populate the model with the fetched data
    setQuery(query);

    if (lastError().isValid()) {
        qDebug() << "Error loading agents:" << lastError().text();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "First Row Data:" << record(0); // Check the label field of the first row
        qDebug() << "Query Executed Successfully:" << query.isActive();
        qDebug() << "Number of Rows Retrieved:" << rowCount();
    }

    // Output the data of each row
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount(); ++i) {
        qDebug() << "Row Data:" << record(i).value("host").toString()
            << record(i).value("label").toString()
            << record(i).value("tag").toString()
            << record(i).value("grpc_port").toInt()
            << record(i).value("grpc_username").toString()
            << record(i).value("grpc_password").toString();
    }

    qDebug() << "Agents Loaded Successfully";
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> AgentModel::roleNames() const
{
    static const char* COLUMN_NAMES[] = {
        "host",
        "label",
        "tag",
        "grpc_port",
        "grpc_username",
        "grpc_password",
        nullptr // Null-terminated array
    };

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames;
    for (int i = 0; COLUMN_NAMES[i] != nullptr; ++i) {
        roleNames[Qt::UserRole + i + 1] = COLUMN_NAMES[i];
    }

    qDebug() << "RoleNames: " << roleNames;
    return roleNames;
}

This is my AgentPanel.qml
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.top: toolBar.bottom
    width: parent.width
    height: 300
    model: agentModel // Use the model retrieved from c++
    Component.onCompleted: {console.log(agentModel.roleNames())}

    delegate: Item {
        width: listView.width
        height: 50

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            color: "lightblue"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: host // !== undefined ? label : "Unknown Label"
                color: "white"
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    // console.log("Row Data:", host, label, tag, grpc_port, grpc_username, grpc_password);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Despite trying various solutions, including directly accessing model properties without using role names, the issue persists.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully display the data in the QML ListView. Thank you!

Finally
This link helped me to solve it:
https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_a_QSqlQueryModel_in_QML
I guess the problem was data QVariant which wasn't defined :

QVariant AgentModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    if (role < Qt::UserRole)
    {
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    }
    else
    {
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }
    return value;
}

